# JavaScript Function Array with variable dimensions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am writing a function which is indexing a 1D Array in more dimension. The user can choose the depth of the index.

eg.

```
var store = ["Alaska", "Alabama", "North Korea", "South Korea"];
```

the user can choose for example depth 1. It means it will be index by the first char of the string

```
index["a"] = ["Alaska", "Alabama"];
index["n"] = ["North Korea"];
```

if the user chooses depth = 2 than it will be 2D Array with index the two beginning chars

```
index["a"]["l"] = ["Alaska", "Alabama"];
```

etc.

How do I accomplish a function which can populate variable Dimension arrays in JavaScript?

```
var indexthis = function(store,depth)
{
  if(depth == "undefined")
  {depth =1;}
//any Suggestions to go on?
};
```

Greetings

Comment: How much are you going to pay me to write this for you?

Comment: What is such an index used for, i.e. what problem are you trying to solve? Is there a reason against simply *searching* the array?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you are asking us to do the work for you

Comment: I was thinking about starting with the last Array var temp[store[i][depth-1]].push(store[i]). And then I need to push temp into another Var temp2.

the index is used to fasten looking for special strings inside an Array

Comment: Loop through the array. if (first character does not have an array) create array. If second character does not have an array, create an array. Push the word to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to meet your requirements:

```
function createIndex(store, depth) {
    var index = {}; 
    depth = depth || 1;

    // loop over each item in the store
    store.forEach(function (item) {
        var lower = item.toLowerCase(),
            current = index,
            char;

        // loop over the characters, building the store structure
        for (i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            char = lower.substr(i, 1); 

            // add the key, if it doesn't exist
            if (!current[char]) {
                current[char] = (i == (depth - 1) ? [] : {});
            }   

            // update the object reference
            current = current[char];
        }   

        // now add the item
        current.push(item);
    }); 

    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
function indexWord(index, word, letters) {
    var letter;
    if (!letters) letters = word.split("");
    while (letters.length) {
        letter = letters.shift().toLowerCase();
        if (!(letter in index)) index[letter] = {_items: []};
        index[letter]._items.push(word);
        indexWord(index[letter], word, letters);
    }
}
```

called like this:

```
var store = ["Alaska", "Alabama", "North Korea", "South Korea"],
    index = {}, i;

for (i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
    indexWord(index, store[i]);
}
```

gives you the following index:

```
{
  a: {
    _items: ["Alaska", "Alabama"],
    l: {
      _items: ["Alaska", "Alabama"],
      a: {
        _items: ["Alaska", "Alabama"],
        s: {
          _items: ["Alaska"],
          k: {
            _items: ["Alaska"],
            a: {
              _items: ["Alaska"]
            }
          }
        },
        b: {
          _items: ["Alabama"],
          a: {
            _items: ["Alabama"],
            m: {
              _items: ["Alabama"],
              a: {
                _items: ["Alabama"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  n: {
    _items: ["North Korea"],
    o: {
      _items: ["North Korea"],
      r: {
        _items: ["North Korea"],
        t: {
          _items: ["North Korea"],
          h: {
            _items: ["North Korea"],
            " ": {
              _items: ["North Korea"],
              k: {
                _items: ["North Korea"],
                o: {
                  _items: ["North Korea"],
                  r: {
                    _items: ["North Korea"],
                    e: {
                      _items: ["North Korea"],
                      a: {
                        _items: ["North Korea"]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  s: {
    _items: ["South Korea"],
    o: {
      _items: ["South Korea"],
      u: {
        _items: ["South Korea"],
        t: {
          _items: ["South Korea"],
          h: {
            _items: ["South Korea"],
            " ": {
              _items: ["South Korea"],
              k: {
                _items: ["South Korea"],
                o: {
                  _items: ["South Korea"],
                  r: {
                    _items: ["South Korea"],
                    e: {
                      _items: ["South Korea"],
                      a: {
                        _items: ["South Korea"]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where either `index["a"]["l"]._items` or `index.a.l._items` can be used to access `["Alaska", "Alabama"]`.

Comment: This seems more useful despite departing a bit from the OPs requirements.

Comment: The OP's requirements cannot be met anyway. Unless of course you use nested arrays instead of objects and define one-letter properties on those arrays themselves. This is an unclean approach. And does not translate to JSON.

Comment: Well, the OP never asked for results at the interim keys. Don't get me wrong, I _like_ what you've done (+1 btw). It's just not what was asked for... and the fact that the OP selected [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24654836/621962) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/F8cD4/)) which doesn't provide results on the interim keys sort of supports my point.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Well, yes, I thought I build a full index right-away.

Comment: I'm not sure if such a colossal waste of memory really serves any useful purpose, though. I mean, look what it does with a four-word input, think what it does with a 4000-word input. I'm pretty sure there is a better algorithm out there to do this kind of thing. Since the OP does not really tell what he wants to achieve in the first place, this is nothing more than an academic example for basic recursion.